# Clojure string splitting results in IllegalArgumentException

Tags: clojure

CLOJURE

Hi everyone, I am new to clojure. I would like to update my record with a split string.

```
(defrecord Learning [Name Age Gender])
(def person [:Name :Age :Gender])

(let person 
(clojure.string/split "John,12,Male" #","))
```

I am able to split the string but it throws an exception
`IllegalArgumentException let requires a vector for its binding in ShipDataRecord:1  clojure.core/let (core.clj:3965)`

Can Someone kindly explain how should I go about doing it?

Comment: You are not new but very very new to clojure. Please read clojure documentation and see how to use `let`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you missed a lot.

First, you using `def` the wrong way. All variables in clojure are immutable. So, after you defined some variable you can't change its value, but you can rebind it with a new value in any local context using `let`.

Second, your using of let is incorrect. Try to read [Clojure Docs](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/let):

```
(let [x 1]
     x)
```

`let` creates new context by binding some variables with new values. `[x 1]` means that you bind value 1 to the variable x. But outside of `let` x won't change.

What you want to do is:

```
(defrecord Learning [Name Age Gender])

(def person
  (apply ->Learning
         (clojure.string/split "John,12,Male" #",")))
```